# Nginx proxy is not loading static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I've deployed this app (polynote https://github.com/polynote) on a remote machine (listening on port 8192) and now I want the UI to be accessible through browser. It all works fine using ssh port-forwarding. Now I want to setup some rules using nginx  (which I already use to proxy things like jupyter) to make this automatic. This is the basic rule I used

```
location /polynote {
   proxy_pass              http://localhost:8192;
   proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}
```

When trying to connect from the browser to `remote-machine:/polynote' I see connections arriving in the server log

```
[blaze-selector-1] INFO org.http4s.blaze.channel.nio1.NIO1SocketServerGroup - Accepted connection from /127.0.0.1:46673
```

but the browser page remains blank and no errors is logged anywhere.

Inspecting the network using Chrome dev tools I see these data arriving in the Network tab

[image]
while a normal working installation (tried in my machine) reports this Network traffic

[image]

Do you have any idea why I am loosing static files?

Comment: Sometimes frontends require a full path to display its ui. So if you are going to server in a different path than (let's say) localhost:8000, then you need to specify it. E.g: location:8000/polynote

Comment: sorry not sure I got your point: where should I specify this?